# Error using tsyringe decorators in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, dependency-injection, typescript-decorator, tsyringe

I'm trying to use [tsyringe](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe/issues/225) typescript library but couldn't even add any decorators as VsCode complains about them.

I'm using typescript 5.

Here's the `tsconfig.json` - it has the required `experimentalDecorators` and `emitDecoratorMetadata` documented by *tsyringe* docs.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "src/",
      "declaration": true,
      "declarationDir": "build/",
      "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "ESNext",
      "useDefineForClassFields": true,
      "module": "ESNext",
      "lib": [
         "ESNext",
         "DOM",
         "DOM.Iterable",
         "ES2021.String"
      ],
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "strict": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": false,
      "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "typeRoots": [
         "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
   },
   "include": [
      "./src/*", "@types"
   ],
   "exclude": [
      "./src/tests/**"
   ]
}
```

**Errors**:

*Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression*

```
@injectable()
export class WorkerRuntime implements Runtime { ... }
```

*Decorators are not valid here*

```
constructor(@inject("pageMonitor") private pageAwaiter: Awaiter, ...)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the directory structure

```
C:.
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│
└───src
    │   index.ts
    │   runtime.ts
    │
    ├───content
    │   │   content.runtime.ts
    │   │   index.ts
    │
    └───worker
        │   index.ts
        │   worker.runtime.ts
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I use the `@injectable` in a file **directly** under `src`, VsCode does not complain - like `runtime.ts` file. But if I use it in a file within a folder under `src` like `src/worker/worker.runtime.ts` VsCode complains. However, I cannot change the tsconfig.json  to `include: ["./src/**"]` (double star) - it does not allow it:

```
File specification cannot end in a recursive directory wildcard ('**'): './src/**'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without knowing your files and folders structure, but these errors means that `experimentalDecorators` is not taken into account, and I highly suspect it's because your TypeScript file location either does not match the glob patterns you have configured in the `include` property, or matches the `exclude` pattern.

Comment: Doubt it as every typescript file is under `src` directory.  Nevertheless, I've updated the question with the directory structure

Comment: update: you have something there. If I use the `@injectable` in a file **directly** under `src`, VsCode does not complain. But if I use it in a file within a folder under `src` like `src/worker/worker.runtime.ts` VsCode complains. However, I cannot change the tsconfig.json  to `include: ["./src/**"]` (double star) - it does not allow it.

Comment: Well I think the actual glob pattern you need is `./src/**/*.ts`